# How get last value of MongoDB property?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoid

I am trying to recovery data on a MongoDB collection that changed.

`I.e. - property: false -> true`, I don't have a backup of the entire collection.

Is there any way to know what is the last property value before `$set` operation? Like history of actions on data?

It could be based on a timestamp too.

Example: Collection name `Users`

Before change:

```
{name:"xxxx1", address:"yyyy1", test:false}
{name:"xxxx2", address:"yyyy2", test:true}
{name:"xxxx3", address:"yyyy3", test:false}
{name:"xxxx4", address:"yyyy4", test:true}
```

After change:

```
{name:"xxxx1", address:"yyyy1", test:true}
{name:"xxxx2", address:"yyyy2", test:true}
{name:"xxxx3", address:"yyyy3", test:true}
{name:"xxxx4", address:"yyyy4", test:true}
```

I want to know all entities with value `test :false`:

```
{name:"xxxx1", address:"yyyy1", test:false}
{name:"xxxx3", address:"yyyy3", test:false}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you had some versioning plugin installed on your collections before this update operation, it is not possible to extract changes. However you might want to look into [oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) which is a capped collection that stores an ordered history of logical writes to a MongoDB database.